# Complex numbers product using only three multiplications

Tags: algorithm, math, complex-numbers

We do complex number multiplication as follows:

```
(a + i * b) * (c + i * d) = (a * c - b * d) + i * (a * d + b * c)
```

The real and imaginary parts of the result are

```
real part = (a * c - b * d)
imag part = (a * d + b * c)
```

This involves four real multiplications. How can we do it with only three real multiplications?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about multiplying complex numbers It should be on [math.se]

Comment: @MikeW It probably wouldn't be off topic over there, but I don't see how it's off topic *here* either. Complex numbers are important in plenty of programming tasks and OP is essentially asking for an *algorithm*.

Comment: This is essentially Karatsuba multiplication used heavily in Algorithms.

Comment: @delnan What you say might be true, but this is a programming site. As the question is stated it's not clear that it's anything other than a problem in mathematics.

Comment: @MikeW I thing you're wrong here. If the question had something like "in our program we're multiplying..." it would be directly related to stackoverflow.

Comment: @kilotaras This is why we have a voting system.

Comment: I think that fast complex multiplication originated with Gauss.  Can anybody provide an approximate date or historical reference with the programming solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are interested in two numbers : `A=ac−bd` and `B=ad+bc`. 
Compute three real multiplications `S1=ac`, `S2=bd`, and `S3=(a+b)(c+d)`. 
Now you can compute the results as
`A=S1−S2` and `B=S3−S1−S2`.

This process is called Karatsuba multiplication and used heavily in Algorithm analysis.

It is used to find the closest pair of points.

Comment: This is from Gauss, not Karatsuba.  Karatsuba multiplication is for the quad precision product of two double precision integers.  In 1960 when this was discovered, multiplication in computers was a slow operation consisting of shift and add-- 32 such operations for a 32 bit integer, as in Russian peasant multiplication.  Yes, the Gauss and Karatsuba procedures are very similar, but the goals are different.  And Karatsuba can be applied recursively to larger problems; not Gauss.

Comment: @richard1941 You're not wrong, but the Gauss algorithm is essentially a special case of the basic step of karatsuba with base i. I am not sure what the real value of making a distinction is apart from historical accuracy.

Answer (score 12):

For completeness, I'd like to point out [Gauss' complex multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Complex_multiplication_algorithm), which is another way to do complex multiplication with only three multiplies. To summarize, you compute

```
k1 = c * (a + b)
k2 = a * (d - c)
k3 = b * (c + d)
Real part = k1 - k3
Imaginary part = k1 + k2
```

Answer (score 10):

Vallabh Patade has already answered on how performing the product between two complex numbers with only three real multiplications. The application of **Karatsuba**'s algorithm is indeed the following

```
x = a + i * b;
y = c + i * d;

real(x * y) = a * c - b * d;
imag(x * y) = (a + b) * (c + d) - a * c - b * d;
```

Now the question is: *can we perform the product between two complex numbers with **less** than three real multiplications?*

The answer is **NO** and is provided by **Winograd's theorem** in

```
S. Winograd, "On the number of multiplications required to compute certain functions", Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 23 (1970), 165-179.
```

**The minimum number of multiplications required in the computation of the product between two complex numbers is three**.

Comment: Please, clarify the reason for downvoting. Thanks.

Comment: After I changed my mind on this answer, the software would not allow me to reverse my vote.  Consider this comment a virtual upvote.

Answer (score 8):

Some algorithms, e.g. [Split-radix FFT](https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/273.F10/duhamel.vetterli.fft.review.pdf) set higher expectations on complex multiplication requiring complexity of exactly 3 real multiplications and 3 real additions.

```
(a+ib)(c+id)=ac−bd+i(ad+bc)    

x=a(c−d)
y=a+b
z=a−b
ac-bd=zd+x
ad+bc=yc−x
```

In an FFT, y and z come entirely from the twiddle factors, so they can be precomputed and stored in a look-up table. So the requirement is fulfilled. [FFT Tricks](http://cnx.org/contents/e240a1a1-c1cc-4427-94e1-b9d978c01421@6/Efficient-FFT-Algorithm-and-Pr)

Comment: So 5 additions, but 2 of them can be precomputed?

Comment: Exactly. I stumbled on this trying to understand obscure complexity numbers in Split-radix FFT because 2 out of 5 real additions were missing.

Comment: Notice that now you need to keep 3 real numbers instead of original 2 for each twiddle factor, i.e. a, y, z instead of just a, b. This may have some effect on cache locality. Also, depending on the availability of SIMD intrinsics, it might be better to keep it as just 2 real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Winograd is practically correct if you want to do a mixture of adds and multiplies. But if you only want to do complex multiplies,  work in logpolar representation that multiplication is just adding logamplitudes and angles;
but of course logpolar adds are hard!
Logpolar can be nice for limited precision FFTs on e.g. 8 bit logamplitude +j8 bit phase  on microprocessors.